# Using ObjectCollection in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, controls

This is stemmed from another question I had where the solution had me using ObjectCollection.  I have never used an ObjectCollection before and was wondering if anyone knew where I could find more info on it?

Everywhere I look talks briefly at best about the ObjectCollection, but never really says much about it.  I know it is another control, I'm just not sure what it does exactly.

From what I can gather it is more or less a "holder" or container for variables used in the code-behind.  Or possibly a table of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObjectCollection` is provided by the Silverlight Toolkit.  If you have that installed open the Documentation .chm file via the programs menu, its documented in there.

It isn't actually a control even though it is placed in the System,Windows.Controls namespace.  In fact all it is a standard generic `Collection<T>` defined as:-

```
 ObjectCollection : Collection<Object> { }
```

The only reason a separate class is needed at all is because you can't describe generic types in Xaml.